# fsck died with status code 4

Tags: fsck

During boot my laptop says:

```
fsck died with status code 4
```

The man page tells me:

> The exit code returned by fsck is the sum of the following conditions:
>
> [..]
>
> 4    - File system errors left uncorrected

When I try to repair the errors as root, fsck says that my disk is clean:

```
$ fsck /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1, clean [and some things about available blocks]
```

How can I repair my disk?

Comment: Did you try the `-y` option? From `fsck` manual: ` -y     For some filesystem-specific checkers, the -y option will cause the fs-specific fsck to always attempt to fix any detected filesystem  corruption  automatically.   Some-
              times  an  expert may be able to do better driving the fsck manually.  Note that not all filesystem-specific checkers implement this option.  In particular fsck.minix(8)
              and fsck.cramfs(8) does not support the -y option as of this writing.`

Comment: (I assume `fkck` is a typo). Possibly you have another filesystem—are you sure you only have `/dev/sda1`? Check `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @Ketan Unfortunately the `-y` flag does solve my problem. @derobert I ran `fsck` with each of my partitions that show up running `fstab`.

Comment: @Ketan. My system runs again. Your solution solved, although I didn't mentioned it the first time. `fsck -y /dev/sda1` returned the same output as `fsck /dev/sda1`, so I thought it didn't help. But it did! Please write it down in an answer and I'll mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the -y option.

From fsck [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck):

> -y For some filesystem-specific checkers, the -y option will cause the fs-specific fsck     to always attempt to fix any detected filesystem corruption automatically. Some- times an     expert may be able to do better driving the fsck manually. Note that not all filesystem-specific checkers implement this option. In particular fsck.minix(8) and fsck.cramfs(8) does not support the -y option as of this writing.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes fsck shows that a filesystem has no errors, but in reality it has. I had a similar issue once, and if you want to check that filesystem, you have to use force. I'm not sure what type of a filesystem you're using, but let's assume it's ext4:

```
Emergency help:
 -p                   Automatic repair (no questions)
 -n                   Make no changes to the filesystem
 -y                   Assume "yes" to all questions
 -c                   Check for bad blocks and add them to the badblock list
 -f                   Force checking even if filesystem is marked clean
 -v                   Be verbose
 -b superblock        Use alternative superblock
 -B blocksize         Force blocksize when looking for superblock
 -j external_journal  Set location of the external journal
 -l bad_blocks_file   Add to badblocks list
 -L bad_blocks_file   Set badblocks list
```

So, the line you need is:

```
# fsck.ext4 -pvf /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, for me `-pvf` does not perform repair and exits with code 4, while `-yvf` does fix errors.